# Как убрать в textview внутренние отступы?

Tags: android

На картинке показано 2 пример, в красной рамке это стандартный текст в TextView, а в зелёной рамке это текст без отступов который мне нужен.
Может кто подскажет как добиться такого же результата?

[image: Пример]

**UPD:**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView5"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="678901"
      android:includeFontPadding="false"
      android:textSize="28sp"
      android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
      android:fontFamily="monospace"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"/>
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView3"
      android:text="123456"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:includeFontPadding="false"
      android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
      android:textSize="36sp"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView4"
      android:text="3214568"
      android:includeFontPadding="false"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
      android:fontFamily="cursive"
      android:textSize="24sp"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду, что вам надо отцентрировать текст? просто на картинке с зеленой рамке есть отступы, как раз. Попробуйте использовать тэг android:gravity="center"

Comment: Я про отступы по вертикали. Обратите внимание на текст в синей рамке, между с текстом и и синей рамкой есть отступы в несколько пикселей,сверху и снизу, причем снизу отступ больше чем сверху. От указанных отступов и хочу избавится.

Comment: Если бы это был многострочный текст то можно было бы заюзать android:lineSpacingMultiplier="0.5" а так не знаю что делать.

Comment: Попробуйте у первой и второй вью выставить отричательное значение у android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp", к примеру. По идеее должно помочь.

Comment: не работает, да и вообще проект ведет себя странно после установки margin в минус

Comment: Прикрепите код разметки.

Comment: Прикрепил код разметки

Comment: Добавил ответом, у меня в таком виде получилось без отстпупов

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="123456"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"
        android:textSize="36sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="678901"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:text="3214568"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>
```